# .bind(this) not working inside xhr addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

`.bind(this)` is not working inside a response from an xhr request

I've tried to move `.bind(this)` to almost every place I could think but it's still not working

Ultimately I just need to capture `this.obj.id`

```
upload(blob8) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", blob8);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.open(
      "POST",
      "URL"
    );
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${this.state.accessToken}`); //<--- IS WORKING
    // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        this.obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(this.obj);
        console.log(this.obj.id);
        this.uploadMetaData(this.obj.id).bind(this);  // <------- NOT WORKING
      } else {
        console.log("there is an error here");
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

I missed that the callback is referencing two different `this` contexts. Two possible ways to solve this:

```js
upload() {
    var that = this;
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        that.uploadMetaData(this.obj.id); 
    });
}
```

or

```js
upload() {
    var boundUploadMetaData = this.uploadMetaData.bind(this);
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        boundUploadMetaData(this.obj.id); 
    });
}
```

Both will call `uploadMetaData` with `upload()`'s `this` while allowing the callback to still reference the `xhr` object's `this`.

Alternatively, I don't think you need to reference the `xhr` object's `this` at all:

```js
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        this.uploadMetaData(res.id);
    } else {
        console.log("there is an error here");
    }
}.bind(this));
```

**Original answer**:

Assuming this isn't a method for an ES2015 class (it sounds like it isn't if the `this` reference in `upload()` is correct), the callback for `"readystatechange"` will need to be bound to the outer method's (`upload()`) `this`.

You should be able to do either of the following:

```
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  // callback body   
}.bind(this));
```

or, if you're able to use ES2015 syntax, then

```
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
  // callback body   
});
```

since arrow function expressions bind `this` by their lexical scope.

Comment: not working...I'm thinking about something. If you look at the xhr command it has .this already inside and it uses to capture the response. Whenever I use .bind(this) the if statement never happens because I'm re writing the contents of .this .

Comment: That makes sense. If you need access to multiple `this` contexts, I think your best bet is to save it off to a variable in the outer scope. I'll update my answer.

Comment: first two dont work because .this is not available......but your third option worked like magic all is well